# $_SESSION retornando nulo

Tags: php

Estou guardando em alguns valores usando `$_SESSION`.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../controller/LocacaoController.php';
if(!empty($_REQUEST['idfilme']) and !empty($_REQUEST['idfita'])){
  $idfilme = $_REQUEST['idfilme'];
  $idfita = $_REQUEST['idfita'];

  $_SESSION['codfilme'] = $idfilme;
  $_SESSION['codfita'] = $idfita;
  echo "entrou aqui";

}
else {

  if(!empty($_SESSION['codfilme']) and !empty($_SESSION['codfita'])){
      $_SESSION['codfita'] = null;
      $_SESSION['codfilme'] = null;
  }
}

?>
```

O código é o seguinte: se no meu outro arquivo eu passar valores para `$_REQUEST['idfilme']` e `$_REQUEST['idfita']` então ele entra no `IF` e guarda na session, Agora caso os `$_REQUEST` estiverem vazios ele vai pro `ELSE` e adiciona `NULL` as `$_SESSION['codfita']` e `$_SESSION['codfilme']`

Ai em outro arquivo recupero esses valores:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once '../controller/LocacaoController.php';


  $idCliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
  $idFita = $_SESSION['codfita'];

  $idFilme = $_SESSION['codfilme'];
  var_dump($idFita);
  var_dump($idFilme);

  if(!empty($_SESSION['codfita'])){

    $idFita = $_SESSION['codfita'];
    $idFilme = $_SESSION['codfilme'];
  }

  ?>
```

Só que o problema é que mesmo eu passando valores para `$_REQUEST['idfilme']` e `$_REQUEST['idfita']` e entrando no `IF` do código 1, na outra tela ele está retornando `null`.

OBS: Não se preocupem com os `$_REQUEST`, e a ligação dos arquivos pois está funcionando corretamente, o problema é as `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Tenta remover seu include no início só para testar. Talvez você está iniciando novamente a session ou configurando alguma coisa de forma inesperada.

Comment: session_start();
Deve estar na primeira linha antes de qualquer include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que vai resolver isso bem simples assim:

```
<?php session_start();
```

Coloca o session_start(); como primeira coisa, antes de tudo e uma única vez, em ambos os teus arquivos.

Comment: ainda retorna null, tipo no codigo 1, dentro IF se eu colocar um ECHO para msotrar se ele está guardando dentro da SESSION, ele mostra os valores, mas ja no outro arquivo, ele retorna num como n tivesse entrado no IF

Comment: No teu código atualizado o session_start() não está no começo. consegue colocar perfeitamente no início? Aproveita e já substitui os `AND`por `&&`

Comment: Acho que já encontrei o erro, veja no codigo 1  quando passo valores para o $_REQUEST possuem valor, eles entram no IF certo ? só que nesse mesmo arquivo do codigo 1, eu tenho um botao "SUBMIT"  que da reload a tela, fazendo que ele entre no else. e passando NULL pras sesssion

Comment: Uma dica então é substituir o `echo "chegou aqui";`por `print_r($_REQUEST);` assim mostrando o que está chegando ao teu $_SESSION